# Spacing Columns In Beamer

Tags: beamer, columns

I am having trouble getting a pair of columns together in the `\columns` environment in beamer. As the other related question suggest I have tried to modify the width of the column, but so far it has not changed anything. The slide looks like this:

[image: Slide]

And the code is the following:

```
\begin{frame}
Constrained parameters are stored in the file \texttt{work/models/func1.mdl}. Although there are some public parameters, by default all particle masses and external function calculated ones, by modifying the file it is posible to set all of them as public. \\ \pause
Finally, lets see some of the methods that can make the calculation of spectrum and of all public model constrains:\pause
\begin{columns}
\column[t]{0.5cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item \texttt{sortOddParticles(txt)}\\
\item \texttt{qNumbers(pName,\&spin2, \&charge3,\&cdim)}\footnote{The \& represents a memory direction in C}\\
\item \texttt{pdg2name(nPDG)}\\
\item \texttt{pMass(pName)}\\
\item \texttt{nextOdd(n,\&pMass)}\\
\end{itemize}
\column[t]{5cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item \texttt{findVal(name,\&val)}\\
%\item \texttt{findValW(name)}\\
%\item \texttt{printVar(FD)}\\
%\item \texttt{printMasses(FD,sort)}\\
%\item \texttt{printHiggsMasses(FD,sort)}\\
\end{itemize}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `\footnote` causes the trouble, but you can use `\footnotemark[1]` and `\footnotetext[1]{}` to circumvent the problem.
- `\column[t]{0.5cm}` is of course way too small for the content of the column

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth, T]
    \begin{column}{.47\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \texttt{sortOddParticles(txt)}
            \item \texttt{qNumbers(pName, \&spin2, \&charge3, \&cdim)}\footnotemark
            \item \texttt{pdg2name(nPDG)}
            \item \texttt{pMass(pName)}
            \item \texttt{nextOdd(n,\&pMass)}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.47\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \texttt{findVal(name,\&val)}
            \item \texttt{findValW(name)}
            \item \texttt{printVar(FD)}
            \item \texttt{printMasses(FD,sort)}
            \item \texttt{printHiggsMasses(FD, sort)}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}

\footnotetext{The \& represents a memory direction in C}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The main point seems to be the \footnote. I modified some more aspects but for more or less aesthetical reasons.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Constrained parameters are stored in the file
\texttt{work/models/func1.mdl}. Although there are some public
parameters, by default all particle masses and external function
calculated ones, by modifying the file it is posible to set all of
them as public. \\ \pause Finally, lets see some of the methods that
can make the calculation of spectrum and of all public model
constrains:\pause

\begin{columns}[t,onlytextwidth]
 \begin{column}{0.47\linewidth}
  \begin{itemize}
   \item \texttt{sortOddParticles(txt)}\\
   \item \texttt{qNumbers(pName,\&spin2, \&charge3,\&cdim)}%\footnote{The \& represents a memory direction in C}\\
   \item \texttt{pdg2name(nPDG)}\\
   \item \texttt{pMass(pName)}\\
   \item \texttt{nextOdd(n,\&pMass)}\\
  \end{itemize}
 \end{column}
 \begin{column}{0.47\linewidth}
  \begin{itemize}
   \item \texttt{findVal(name,\&val)}\\
   \item \texttt{findValW(name)}\\
   \item \texttt{printVar(FD)}\\
   \item \texttt{printMasses(FD,sort)}\\
   \item \texttt{printHiggsMasses(FD,sort)}\\
  \end{itemize}
 \end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As can be found in the manual: "First a word of warning: Using footnotes is usually not a good idea." [section 12.12 in beameruserguide.pdf]